# restrict remote desktop users access server from internet

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I have approx 10 remote desktop users who are accessing a server from a remote desktop connection. 5 users are connecting to the server within the local environment and the remaining 5 are accessing from the internet.

I want to restrict the local 5 users from connecting to the server from the internet. Please guide.

Server OS: Windows Server 2012 Standard

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to be the administrator of this network, the simplest solution would
be to restrict access to TCP and UDP ports 3389 for those users toward the Internet.

The tool is the firewall, either on the router or on each of the 5 local computers,
with a firewall rule using these port numbers and the Internet IP address of the
server.

Comment: can we configure logon to in active directory users?

Comment: I don't think Group Policy allows this level of detailed control, but you may use it to push firewall rules.